# How to use chaining promise together with for loops of arrays?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js

So, I have this code. I'm trying to debug it in forever. I dont know why it is returning error. I might have some element of promise I forgot or I have something wrong with my array.push 'cause when I look at the log, it throws error on line where I push some objects into array.

Here is my code so far:

```
router.post('/inventory/product/stocks/add/(:id)', authenticationMiddleware(), function(req, res, next) {
const db = require('../db.js')

var product_no = req.params.id
var cog = req.body.cog
var size_slug = req.body.size_slug
var size_name = req.body.size_name
var rowinserted = 0
var initial_stock = req.body.initial_stock
var stock_id = new Array
var batch_id = new Array
var stock = new Array
var batch = new Array

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('one');
    // Getting product product_slug for product_sku

    let sql = `SELECT product_slug
               FROM inventory_tbl
               WHERE product_no = ?`

    db.query(sql, [req.params.id], (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            var product_slug = results[0].product_slug
            resolve(product_slug)
        }
    })
})
.then(function(value) {
    console.log('two');
    // Insert product sizes together with its initial stock

    for (var x = 0; x < size_slug.length; x++) {
        var product_sku = value + size_slug[x]
        var slug = size_slug[x]
        var name = size_name[x]
        var initial_stock = initial_stock[x]
        console.log(product_sku);
        if (size_slug[x] != '') {
            stock.push({
                product_sku: product_sku,
                product_no: product_no,
                size_slug: slug,
                size_name: name,
                total_stock: initial_stock,
                available_stock: initial_stock
            })
        }
        console.log(stock);
    }

    for (var x = 0; x < size_slug.length; x++) {
        var product_sku = value + size_slug[x]
        var initial_stock = initial_stock[x]
        if (size_slug[x] != '') {
            batch.push({
                product_no: product_no,
                product_sku: product_sku,
                production_date: mysql.raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
                batch_cog: cog,
                initial_stock: initial_stock,
                stock_left: initial_stock
            })
        }
        console.log(batch);
    }

    return value
})
.then(function(value) {
    console.log('three');
    // Insert rows to product_tbl and stock_tbl

    for (var i = 0; i < stock.length; i++) {
        let sql = `INSERT INTO product_tbl(product_sku, product_no, size_slug, size_name, total_stock, available_stock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

        db.query(sql, [stock[i].product_sku, req.params.id, stock[i].size_slug, stock[i].size_name, stock[i].total_stock, stock[i].available_stock], (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) throw error
            db.query(`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id;`, (error, results, fields) => {
                stock_id[i] = results[0].id
            })
        })

        sql = `INSERT INTO stocks_tbl(product_no, product_sku, production_date, batch_cog, initial_stock, stock_left) VALUES (?, ?, CURRENT_DATE, ?, ?, ?)`

        db.query(sql, [req.params.id, batch[i].product_sku, batch[i].batch_cog, batch[i].initial_stock, batch[i].stock_left], (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) throw error
            db.query(`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id;`, (error, results, fields) => {
                batch_id[i] = results[0].id
            })
        })
        rowsupdated++
    }

    return value
})
.then(function(value) {
    console.log('four');
    // Render the web page
    if (rowinserted != sizeslug.length) {
        req.flash('error', error)

        res.redirect('/admin/inventory/product/stock/add/' + req.params.id)
    } else {
        req.flash('success', 'Data added successfully!')
        res.redirect('/admin/inventory/product/stock/add/' + req.params.id)
    }
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error');
    // Error handler

    for (var i = 0; i < rowinserted; i++) {
        let sql = `DELETE FROM product_tbl WHERE product_sku = ?`

        db.query(sql, [stock_id[i]], (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) throw error
        })

        sql = `DELETE FROM stocks_tbl WHERE product_sku = ?`

        db.query(sql, [batch_id[i]], (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) throw error
        })
    }

    res.redirect('/admin/inventory/product/stock/add/' + req.params.id)
})
})
```

My log returns:

one

two

error

Edit: The process stops (I'm not sure the specific line but according to the log output) after **console.log('two')** because I tried putting some log as well after the for loops but they don't proceed there. It just go to the .catch/error.

Comment: Did you take into consideration to use a library for this ? If yes I suggest to use `when`. It is really powerful. https://github.com/cujojs/when

Comment: If the `value` parameter you return is not a promise then you can't really chain the function with a `.then` since it doesn't return a promise

Comment: @Strawberry JS has three different quotes, single, double and backticks.  Single and double have no behavior difference but backticks allow you to do multi-line strings and templating.

Comment: @MichaelWestcott Fair enough!

Comment: callback hell :) If you would have used any library like Q or bluebird or even async/await(if nodejs>6.11) then you will never face error like this.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of outputting a string in `console.log('error');` dump out an actual `error` object that you receive in the `catch` handler. It will give additional details of why and where it fails. I suspect that the code after `console.log('two');` throws an exception and then you unintentionally swallow it below.

Consider splitting your code into separate thematic functions. That way you will be able to maintain and spot the errors (or typos) much easier.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the output, i can see that `console.log(product_sku);` this is not getting printed. So, actually the problem is `var initial_stock = initial_stock[x]`. You have declared the local variable(to your then callback function) with same name as global variable(to your route.post callback functions) and now your global `initial_stock` variable is masked with local one, which is not an array (actually is undefined). So try changing the variable name to something else in your `then` block and see if problem disappear.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no window, the code is node.js. Anyway, intial_stock isn't global it's scoped to the router.post callback function. Apart from that you're probably on the right track

Comment: Ahh i see. I think i missed the above context and focused on the problematic code. I will edit my answer. Thanks @MichaelWestcott